# How should I implement and IF statement in my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, c#-4.0

Here is my code :

```
string cmdstr = "UPDATE itemsordered i " +
                "INNER JOIN"+
                    "(  SELECT itemsOrdered_quantity, itemsOrdered_ID,  "+
                            "IF itemsOrdered_quantity = '"+quantityTxtBox.Text+"' SELECT 'EQUAL' "+
                            "IF itemsOrdered_quantity < '" + quantityTxtBox.Text + "' SELECT 'LESS' " +
                            "IF itemsOrdered_quantity > '" + quantityTxtBox.Text + "' SELECT 'MORE'  " +
                        "END AS r "+
                        "FROM itemsordered "+
                    ") res ON i.itemsOrdered_ID = res.itemsOrdered_ID "+
               "INNER JOIN stocksdb s ON s.stock_ID = i.stock_ID " +
               "SET s.stock_quantity = (s.stock_quantity + i.itemsOrdered_quantity), " +
                   "s.stock_dateUpdated = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "', " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_status = 'RECEIVED', " +
                   "i.itemsOrdered_dateReceived = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "'" +
                   "WHERE i.itemsOrdered_ID = '" + idTxtBox.Text + "' AND res.r = 'EQUAL'";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdstr, db.mycon);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("ITEM RESTOCKED!");
```

What I actually want to do is if the `itemsOrdered_quantity` is equal to the value in the `quantityTxtBox` then it will update the `s.stock_quantity` by adding the amount on the `itemsOrdered_quantity` to the current amount.

There are also other IF clauses I would like to make.  But I would like to solve this dilemma first.

It returns an error on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` and points to my SQL string 'near' my IF statement.

Comment: Please use parameters instead of concatenating strings together. Currently your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection), so a user could help themselves to your data, delete or update any fields or rows they want etc. etc. Its also better for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But I already have handled keypress events to only allow numbers on the TextBox

Comment: Still better for performance reasons, as if the query text changes then a new query plan is made - at the moment you're changing the query text every time; if you're using parameters, you're not changing the text with each execution and so a plan can be re-used. Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html) if you'd like to know more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses the [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//case.html) statement for that, basic syntax is:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = b THEN c ELSE d END CASE
```

You can also do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = b THEN c 
            WHEN a > b THEN e
            ELSE d END CASE
```

Comment: Thanks! How will I be able to update the table based on the result?

Comment: Try changing "IF itemsOrdered_quantity = '"+quantityTxtBox.Text+"' SELECT 'EQUAL' " to something like "CASE WHEN itemsOrdered_quantity = '"+quantityTxtBox.Text+"' THEN 'EQUAL' " and do this for the three lines

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use [if statment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
   SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');
   //output  -> 'yes'
  //if 1<2 is true then return  `yes` if not true return `no`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when  itemsOrdered_quantity= '"+quantityTxtBox.Text+"'then 'EQUAL' else (case when itemsOrdered_quantity<  '"+quantityTxtBox.Text+"' then 'LESS' else  'MORE' end ) end) as r from itemsordered
```